# Effeciently update data in firestore flutter and prevent many writes

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to prevent as much write data to firestore and make it as efficient. The user can edit their profile that consists of three sections. The way i have it at the moment is that the firestore update is stored in a method which updates all the sections even if only one section is updated.

I would like it so that if the user only edits one section then that is only updated within firestore.

My code

```
    await firestoreInstance
        .collection("users")
        .document(firebaseUser.uid)
        .updateData({
      "images": _imagesUrl,
      "name": firstNameController.text,
      "biography": biographyController.text,
    });
```

Comment: I'm not at all clear what you're trying to optimize here.

Comment: From what I understand each data that is updated in the document of firestore it takes up a write which costs. So im trying to prevent updating all three data fields even though lets say the user doesn't edit name data field to be updated

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that we have no way to know the current value of any of these fields.

If you know the current value, you can compare the current and new values and only send it to the database if they are not the same.

If you don't know the current value, then loading the current value is probably more costly than simply sending all three fields to the database.

The reason for that is that Firebase charges for (in this scenario):

- document writes - each document you modify incurs a cost, but that cost does not depend on the amount of data you update in that document
- document reads
- bandwidth of data read by the client

So Firestore doesn't charge bandwidth for data you send to the database. So while only sending modified fields may save bandwidth, it won't save in Firebase cost on that front, while having to read the document to determine what fields are modified will definitely cost more.

Comment: Is there a source that confirms that only a document with many fields is equal to one cost  rather than costs to each field same goes for read too. I am only using firebase storage to store images and firestore for data

Comment: If you check where I work, you'll see that I probably qualify as a reasonably reliable source for information on this. ;-)    But also: it is called a **document write** charge for a reason: it's a charge for every time the server writes to a document for you, which happens once for the single `updateData` call in your code snippet. If you feel like more reassurance that this is true, give it a try - as it is fairly easy to verify.

Comment: Ahh i did not see. Would this be the same for firebase storage too or just firestore?

Comment: The two products are completely separate, so the above applies to Firestore only. If you want to learn more about the charges of Cloud Storage, check the pricing page, see how it applies to your use-case, and then do some experiments to validate your hypothesis. If you're seeing unexpected results and can't find an explanation by searching, I'd recommend posting a new question.